# How can I insert data to table B with more columns than table A with the same ID (ID matches from both tables)?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, where-clause

So here is my problem, how can i do this :

user with ID = 7 from table A with 3 columns want to insert data to table B with 4 columns but with the same id.

Table A :

| Id | name | password |

| 7  | john | password |

| 9  | mark | password |

| 12 | yuta | password |

Table B :

| Id | user_id | food | drink |

| 1  |    7    | oats | milk  |

| 2  |    9    | fish | water |

| 3  |    12   | pear | fanta |

How can i achieve table b in 1 query? both id in both table are primary keys and im using mysql

here's the code i was trying to do :

`INSERT INTO table_b SET food = :food, drink = :drink, ( user_id) SELECT a.id FROM table_a u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * WHERE name = :name AND password = :password)`

i know the query is wrong but thats the closest i can do. pls help thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should just use a unique code to link them together.

you can have the code stored in a variable like this

```
$unique = time().rand(1000, 9999);
//You should have something like this 16659154332358
```

Create a column that will recieve this value in your database.

Now they have a relationship

Comment: hii, thank you for answering. how to link them afterwards? is it like WHERE $unique = '16659154332358'  or?

Comment: before linking them you have to create the column "unique or code or link" for table A and table B inside your database.

I think you should contact me via so that i can further understand your problem . www.hybridsoft.com.ng or linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/ojosolomon/?originalSubdomain=uk